# Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in C:\wamp\www\

Tags: php

I'm getting an error that class is not found, but I clearly have the right path for where it is located:

```
<?php

require_once('stripe-php-2.1.0/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');



Stripe::setApiKey('my_key');

var_dump($_POST['stripe-token']);

?>
```

Every article I've come across all claim that the problem is (not including the right path) in the require_one, include, or require. (I've tried all 3).  But still no luck.  My database calls follow the same format and my WAMP server has no problem creating my database class.

This is copied directly from my file explore (copy paste)

website\stripe-php-2.1.0\stripe\lib\Stripe.php

My php file that I am using to try and access Stripe sits in the same place as 'website'.

PHP version 5.5.12

tutorial references:  http://www.larryullman.com/2013/01/09/writing-the-php-code-to-process-payments-with-stripe/

Other reference:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lka_JBM9bbY

[image]

Comment: Including the file doesn't seem to be the problem... The class isn't found. Are you sure `class Stripe` is in the Stripe.php file?

Comment: @BitwiseCreative , added a screenshot above

Comment: Try `require_once(__DIR__ . '/stripe-php-2.1.0/stripe/lib/Stripe.php');`

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it either.  @Vladimir Ramik suggested putting die("here); in the Stripe.php file.  It did print "here", so the path is correct.  It has to be something else.

Comment: Good man! Sublime :) Below posted with the namespace got it right. Looks like posting the file has resolved this for you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because it uses a namespace. Try:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('my_key');
```

Comment: Well that got me past that error, thanks!

but now I have an undefined index error



        $('#payment-form').submit(function(e){
      $form = $(this);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, function(status, response){
        var token = response.id;
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripe-token"/>').val(token));
        $form.get(0).submit();
      });

      return false;

    });

Comment: Great! Sounds like I answered your question. Mind accepting my answer? The undefined index error is a separate matter, and you may benefit from posting a separate question.

Comment: Yes, I'll accept it - but do you have any idea why this index isn't being found?

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why you're getting the index error, not from a glance at the info provided in your main question and your comment. That's why I suggested posting a new question, so you could provide more details, with code formatting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to initialize all classes.

```
require_once ("stripe_folder/init.php");
```

then use namespaces:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('key_key_key_key_key_key');
```