# Getting a fatal error when autoloading a PHP class

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments, autoload

I am attempting to use Cartalyst, a comprehensive PHP Library for Stripe payments. Here is a link to their documentation: https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/1.0. Here is the code I am trying to get to work:

```
$stripe    = Stripe::make('your-stripe-api-key');
$customers = $stripe->customers()->all();

foreach ($customers['data'] as $customer) {
    var_dump($customer['email']);
}
```

When I run the code above (in my real code I have my api inserted), I receive the following error: `Fatal error: Class 'Stripe' not found in on line 247`. I have triple-checked everything I know to check and I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is. I have "autoloaded" the Stripe Cartalyst library and the Stripe library.

Also, here is my composer code that is generating the autoload files:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cartalyst/stripe": "~1.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: @PedroLobito How do I fix this? I can't rename the packages or they will not download. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you for the link and sample code. I have read the link and I have also tried your sample code however, I am still receiving the same error message: `Class 'Stripe' not found in`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921871/fatal-error-class-stripe-not-found-in-c-wamp-www

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It needs the namespace `\Stripe`, try:

```
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('your-stripe-api-key');
```

Comment: Okay so I have tried these two snippets of code. When I tried `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('your-stripe-api-key');`, it removed the original error I was receiving however, I am not receiving a new error: `Call to a member function customers() on a non-object in` which is this line of code: `$customers = $stripe->customers()->all();`.

Comment: Here is the link to the exact code I am trying to run: https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/1.0#retrieve-all-customers-2

Comment: That's a new question, please open a new one :)

Comment: @three3 try var_dump($stripe); and see what you've

Comment: You **should open a new question**, otherwise your question isn't valid for future users. Sorry matte.

Comment: @NishanthMatha When I run `var_dump($stripe);` it returns `NULL`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PedroLobito I would be happy to open another question but the solution to my original problem still exists. The answer you provided is just one step closer to the full solution. Do you have any extra thoughts on how to get this thing fully working? I will be more than happy to accept your answer then!

Comment: @three3 Pedora is right probaly open a new question and post your latest problem there. or edit the current question to reflect your new problem. before that voteup this answer as it solved your first problem: class not found

Comment: @NishanthMatha the OP shouldn't reformulate the question as it invalidates previous answers. This is common practice at SO.

Comment: I am posting a new question now. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: @PedroLobito Here is the link to the new question. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: This answer, while pointing into the right direction, is wrong, because it changes the original call to `make()` into `setApiKey()`.